# why the pdf highlight just works in a small pieces of area

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf

I am trying to locate the latex pdf position by source inforation. Passing the source line, column, the [synctex](https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex) will return the coordinate of the location in pdf. the server side api may return data like this:

```
{
            "page": 2,
            "h": 160.6675,
            "v": 345.6228,
            "x": 185.5741,
            "y": 343.85944,
            "width": 343.71106,
            "height": 9.6238985
        }
```

on the client side, I am uisng react-pdf-highlighter component to highlight the pdf area, this is how I put the server side coordinate into react-pdf-highlighter:

```
const clientCoordinate = (position: PdfPosition[]) => {
        var hl = new Array<IHighlight>;
        position.forEach((item: PdfPosition) => {
            let sc: Scaled = {
                x1: item.h,
                y1: item.v,
                x2: item.x,
                y2: item.y,
                width: item.width,
                height: item.height
            };
            let sca = new Array();
            sca.push(sc);
            var pos: ScaledPosition = {
                pageNumber: item.page,
                usePdfCoordinates: true,
                boundingRect: sc,
                rects: sca
            };
            var hightLight: IHighlight = {
                id: uuidv4.toString(),
                position: pos,
                content: {},
                comment: {
                    text: 'Flow or TypeScript?',
                    emoji: ''
                }
            };
            hl.push(hightLight);
        });
        return hl;
    }
```

the client pdf was highlighted but just works in a small area:

[image]

I have tried to read the source code of [react-pdf-highlighter](https://github.com/agentcooper/react-pdf-highlighter) and I have already specify the coordinate to pdf coordinate, why still highlight the small pieces of area? what I want the highlight may look like this:

[image]

BTW, my pdf scale ratio is 1.

Comment: I may not be the scale issue because when I tweak small the pdf scale the highlight area still not change to higher or more wide. @KJ